# Google map marker and navigation in javafx

Tags: javafx-2

I have a javafx google map application where i can search for a location. When i run my app, the map is getting displayed but the marker is not getting displayed and when i search for a location it is not navigating and getting pointed to that location. Can you please help me with this?
    package application;

```
import java.net.URL;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class GoogleApp extends Application {

    private Scene scene;
    MyBrowser myBrowser;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    private Stage stage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
        myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
        Scene scene = new Scene(myBrowser);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setWidth(800);
        stage.setHeight(480);
        stage.show();
    }

    class MyBrowser extends Pane {

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

        public MyBrowser() {
            final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("demo.html");
            webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());
            webEngine.setOnAlert(new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(WebEvent<String> e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
            });

            //getChildren().add(webView);
            final TextField city = new TextField("" + "Guntur");
            //final TextField latitude = new TextField("" + 17.387140 * 1.00007);
            //final TextField longitude = new TextField("" + 78.491684 * 1.00007);
            Button update = new Button("Update");
            update.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //  lat = Double.parseDouble(latitude.getText());
                //  lon = Double.parseDouble(longitude.getText());
                    String cityname = city.getText();
                    System.out.printf("%.2f %.2f%n", lat, lon);
                    webEngine.executeScript("getCityname(' " + cityname + " ') ");
                }
            });

            SplitPane toolbar = new SplitPane();
            HBox hb = new HBox();

            hb.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
            hb.setSpacing(10);
            hb.getChildren().addAll(city, update);
            toolbar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
            toolbar.setDividerPositions(new double[] {.1});
            toolbar.getItems().addAll(hb,webView);
            getChildren().addAll(toolbar);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps</title>
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var latLng1=new google.maps.LatLng(17.387140,78.491684);
  function initialize() {
   var carMarkerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('resources/images/map_marker.png');
     var mapProp = {
       center:latLng1,
       zoom:7,
       //icon:carMarkerImage,
       mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(17.387140,78.491684),
              map: map,
              draggable: true,
              icon: carMarkerImage,
              title: "",
              autoPan: true
          });
          var infobulle = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: "ddddd"
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
              infobulle.open(map, marker);
          });
          
     var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcanvas"), mapProp);
   }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
      
         function getCityname(city) {
         geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = city;
            alert("cityname: " +address);
            
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                alert("Latitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                alert("Longitude: "+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                marker.setPosition(latLng1);
             map.setCenter(latLng1);
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
              } 
              else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            }); 
            }
    </script>
<style>
#mapcanvas {
 height: 360px;
 width: 100%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="mapcanvas">
 </div>
</body>
</html>``
```